# How to turn-off/disable Metal depth testing

Tags: swift, macos, metal

I know how to enable the depth test in Metal using swift.

Just call the *MTLRenderCommandEncoder.setDepthStencilState()* with appropriate *MTLDepthStencilState* object like this and it works fine.

```
renderCommandEncoder.setDepthStencilState( state )
```

to turn it off, I thought this could work but it gives me an error at runtime.

```
renderCommandEncoder.setDepthStencilState( nil )
```

the error:

```
-[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder setDepthStencilState:]:3843: failed assertion `Set Depth Stencil State Validation
depthStencilState must not be nil.
```

it is weird because Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder/1516119-setdepthstencilstate) says that the default value is nil and the function *setDepthStencilState()* takes optional value.

any idea how to turn depth-testing off or am I doing something wrong?

### environment:

- Xcode 13.2
- Swift 5
- deployment target: MacOS 11.1

Comment: I found this really strange as well.  The docs make it seem like it's supposed to be valid to pass nil and get the same behavior as making a depth state with always and write set to false.

Not sure why it causes an assert when their own docs explain that it's valid.  Now I have to go through the trouble of creating a depth state for default behavior.

Comment: This Apple Metal sample might help: <https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/render_passes/calculating_primitive_visibility_using_depth_testing>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable depth test by creating an `MTLDepthStencilState` from `MTLDepthStencilDescriptor` with `depthCompareFunction` set to `always`.

```
let descriptor = MTLDepthStencilDescriptor()
descriptor.depthCompareFunction = .always
let depthStencilState = device.makeDepthStencilState(descriptor: descriptor)
renderCommandEncoder.setDepthStencilState(depthStencilState)
```

Update: just setting the `depthCompareFunction` to `always` will make the depth test always pass, but it will also still write out the depth for all the fragments. If you want to keep the depth buffer in the same state, you can set `isDepthWriteEnabled` to `false`.

Comment: Nice. I looked to see if you could set the compare function to nil, but didn't see that.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use **swift**, but you will understand my logic.

In Metal, you configure depth testing independently from the render pipeline, so you can mix and match combinations of render pipelines and depth tests. The depth test is represented by a **MTLDepthStencilState** object, and like you do with a render pipeline, you can create multiple variation of this object.

Create a new  **MTLDepthStencilState** object and configure it with the following settings:

```
DepthStencilDescriptor* depthStencilDescriptor = DepthStencilDescriptor::alloc()->init();
depthStencilDescriptor->setDepthWriteEnabled(false); /* disable depth write */
_depthStencilStateNoWrite = _device->newDepthStencilState(depthStencilDescriptor);
depthStencilDescriptor->release();
```

Use it whenever you want your object to be ignored by the depth test like so:

```
renderEncoder->setDepthStencilState(_depthStencilStateNoWrite);
```

Comment: This does not disable depth test, it disables writing out the depth, but it will still test fragments against existing value in the depth buffer. To disable test, you will actually need to create an `MTLDepthStencilState` from a descriptor with `depthCompareFunction` set to `always`.

Comment: It does, because **MTLCompareFunctionAlways** is the default value for **MTLDepthStencilState** object.

Comment: My bad, I think the right answer then is combination of both our answers